# Synchronize a Linux system command and a while-loop in Python

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, raspberry-pi

With the RaspberryPi system I have to synchronize a Raspbian system command (`raspivid -t 20000`) with a while loop that reads continuously from a sensor adn stores samples in an array. The Raspbian command start a video recording by the RaspberryPi camera CSI module and I have to be sure that it starts at the same instant of the acquisition by the sensor. I have seen many solution that have confused me among modules like `multiprocessing`, `threading`, `subprocess`, ecc. So far the only thing that I have understood is that the `os.system()` function blocks execution of following python's commands placed in the script as long as it runs. So if I try with:

```
import os
import numpy as np

os.system("raspivid -t 20000 /home/pi/test.h264")
data = np.zeros(20000, dtype="float") #memory pre-allocation supposing I have to save 20000 samples from the sensor (1 for each millisecond of the video)
indx=0
while True:
    sens = readbysensor() #where the readbysensor() function is defined before in the script and reads a sample from the sensor
    data[indx]=sens
    if indx==19999:
         break
    else:
         indx+=1
```

that while-loop will run only when the `os.system()` function will finish. But as I wrote above I need that the two processes are synchronized and work in parallel. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an `&` at the end, to make the process detach to the background:

```
os.system("raspivid -t 20000 /home/pi/test.h264 &")
```

According to `bash` man pages:

> If a command is terminated by the control operator &, the shell
>   executes the command in the background in a subshell. The shell does
>   not wait for the command to finish, and the return status is 0.

Also, if you want to minimize the time it takes for the loop to start after executing `raspivid`, you should allocate your `data` and `indx` prior to the call:

```
data = np.zeros(20000, dtype="float")
indx=0
os.system("raspivid -t 20000 /home/pi/test.h264 &")
while True:
    # ....
```

**Update:**
Since we discussed further in the comments, it is clear that there is no really a need to start the loop "at the same time" as `raspivid` (whatever that might mean), because if you are trying to read data from the I2C and make sure you don't miss any data, you will be best of starting the reading operation prior to running `raspivid`. This way you are certain that in the meantime (however big of delay there is between those two executions) you are not missing any data.
Taking this into consideration, your code could look something like this:

```
data = np.zeros(20000, dtype="float")
indx=0
os.system("(sleep 1; raspivid -t 20000 /home/pi/test.h264) &")
while True:
    # ....
```

This is the simplest version in which we add a delay of 1 second before running `raspivid`, so we have time to enter our `while` loop and start waiting for I2C data.
This works, but it is hardly a production quality code. For a better solution, run the data acquisition function in one thread and the `raspivid` in a second thread, preserving the launch order (the reading thread is started first).
Something like this:

```
import Queue
import threading
import os

# we will store all data in a Queue so we can process
# it at a custom speed, without blocking the reading
q = Queue.Queue()

# thread for getting the data from the sensor
# it puts the data in a Queue for processing
def get_data(q):
    for cnt in xrange(20000):
        # assuming readbysensor() is a
        # blocking function
        sens = readbysensor()
        q.put(sens)

# thread for processing the results
def process_data(q):
    for cnt in xrange(20000):
        data = q.get()
        # do something with data here
        q.task_done()

t_get = threading.Thread(target=get_data, args=(q,))
t_process = threading.Thread(target=process_data, args=(q,))
t_get.start()
t_process.start()

# when everything is set and ready, run the raspivid
os.system("raspivid -t 20000 /home/pi/test.h264 &")

# wait for the threads to finish
t_get.join()
t_process.join()

# at this point all processing is completed
print "We are all done!"
```

Comment: But am I sure `os.system("raspivid -t 20000 /home/pi/test.h264 &")` and the while-loop start at the same instant? It is very important for me.

Comment: What does it mean "at the same instant". There is not such certainty in computing, especially if you are not dealing with RTOS. There is at least the context switching, the execution of `np.zeros()` that comes after the `raspivid` and before the loop, and the overhead of interpreter. I would suggest calling `np.zeros()` before `raspivid` to minimize the delay, but there is not much more you can do in terms of concurrent execution, this is the best you can do. Even if you use threads, there are still similar overheads and context switching delays, etc...

Comment: I would like they start together as a single command. Is it possible if I put the while loop immediately after the `os.system()` without `np.zeros()` or `indx=0` in the between ?

Comment: Again, I am not sure what would clasify as "together", but yes, that is as close as you can get. I would be able to help more if I knew the contents of `readbysensor()`.

Comment: the `readbysensor()` function simply read data from a sensor's register address by the `smbus` module like `bus.read_byte_data(DeviceAddress, AddressToRead)`

Comment: If you are just reading data from I2C, then you can just start reading before you start producing the data. Effectively, start reading on I2C before you start `raspivid`, and you won't have to worry about missing data or starting at the same time.

Comment: I think you have got my issue, thanks and sorry if I were not clear to explain it. I need that when I will watch the video-file I am sure its time coincide with saved sensor data from t=0 to t=20 s. Just a question: you have written in the edit details that I will be best of starting the reading operation prior to running `raspivid` but in your "edited" code it starts with `raspivid` and then it starts sensor reading.

Comment: I didn't edit my code, I just added this information as an update. The code still answers your original question, even if the real issue is not the one in the question, but the question was how to synchronize, not how to catch all the data from the I2C, this is something that evolved in further discussions. But it should be clear now what you need to do.

Comment: I know how to get data from the I2C in a good way, it is not a problem but I have not understood why you have updated the suggestion to start sensor reading before `raspivid` but in your updated code the while-loop appears after `raspivid` instead.

Comment: Ok, I added two examples of how to achieve this. The first one is very simple, and the second one is more complex but a better choice. I didn't test this, but its enough to get you a basic idea.

Comment: Thanks for helps. In the `process_data(q)` function can I, for example, save data into the array? I don't need any other processing  during `raspvid` execution. At the moment I need only to do the simultaneous acquisition from the two sensors (the external sensor and the camera).

Comment: Yes, you can do whatever you like. Just edit process_data function properly. Or if the first example is ok for you, you can avoid all the complications of threadings...

Comment: No, it returns:`TypeError: get_data() argument after * must be a sequence, not instance`. Just a question: but how can I verify that it works correctly. Is it not the case to introduce time stamps somewhere?

Comment: Well, introduce them then. Instead of adding `sens` to a `Queue`, add your custom object which contains the timestamp. This can be a simpler one like string: `sens = "{0}: {1}".format(datetime.now(), readbysensor())`, or a more complex one where you would have your custom class to hold relevant information. About the `TypeError`, pastebin the complete traceback.

Comment: Ok. About the `t_process` function: do you think I could process data anyway inside the `t_get` function rather than to create an other function like `t_process`. However the complete `TypeError` is: `Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 505, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
TypeError: get_data() argument after * must be a sequence, not instance`

Comment: Ok, I've edited the code in the answer. You need to add a comma after the `q`, because `args` must be a sequence. And yes, you can process the data in the `get_data` thus eliminating the need for a `Queue` and another thread.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for my delay. I will try it very soon.

Answer (score 2):

You could rewrite your code as:

```
import subprocess
import numpy as np

n = 20000
p = subprocess.Popen(["raspivid", "-t", str(n), "/home/pi/test.h264"])
data = np.fromiter(iter(readbysensor, None), dtype=float, count=n)
```

`subprocess.Popen()` returns immidiately without waiting for `raspivid` to end.

Comment: I will try your solution and I will make to know results ASAP

Comment: `subprocess.Popen` creates the `subprocess.Popen object` but acquisition does not start

Comment: Sorry was my fault. I did forget the option `-o` before destination folder. Works but acquisition is very noisy.